# CoReleated Update In Oracle

Tags: oracle

hi I am trying to update a table from a select query like below .
The Select statement is giving around 30 records , but the update statement is giving 1300 records . What is the mistake i am doing in this?

```
Update BLTU.BLT_1003_HDR HDR SET L_INSTITUTION = ( 
SELECT 
CASE 
   WHEN CO.CORR_TI LIKE 'B%' THEN '12345'
   WHEN CO.CORR_TI LIKE 'C%' THEN '54321'
END AS INSTITUTION 
FROM WC.CORRES CO,WC.LOANS LO 
            WHERE  LO.LOAN_ID = HDR.LOAN_ID
            AND LO.CORR_ID = CO.CORR_ID
            AND LO.CORR_ID NOT LIKE '111%'
            AND LO.L_CURRENT_STATUS_ID NOT IN (99,98,97)
            AND HDR.L_INSTITUTION IS NULL
             )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use a MERGE statement, which IMO is easier to understand and has the advantage that if needed it can also insert new data into the target table (not needed here):

```
MERGE INTO BLTU.BLT_1003_HDR HDR
  USING (SELECT LO.LOAN_ID,
                CASE 
                  WHEN CO.CORR_TI LIKE 'B%' THEN '12345'
                  WHEN CO.CORR_TI LIKE 'C%' THEN '54321'
                END AS INSTITUTION 
           FROM WC.CORRES CO
           INNER JOIN WC.LOANS LO 
             ON LO.CORR_ID = CO.CORR_ID AND
                LO.CORR_ID NOT LIKE '111%' AND
                LO.L_CURRENT_STATUS_ID NOT IN (99,98,97)) L
    ON (L.LOAN_ID = HDR.LOAN_ID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET HDR.L_INSTITUTION = COALESCE(HDR.L_INSTITUTION, L.INSTITUTION);
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank You . Working like a Charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the part of the correlated update query that allows to select which records should be updated. You should add a `WHERE EXIST` clause to the query, as follows :

```
UPDATE
    BLTU.BLT_1003_HDR HDR 
SET L_INSTITUTION = ( 
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN CO.CORR_TI LIKE 'B%' THEN '12345'
            WHEN CO.CORR_TI LIKE 'C%' THEN '54321'
        END AS INSTITUTION 
    FROM WC.CORRES CO,WC.LOANS LO 
    WHERE
        LO.LOAN_ID = HDR.LOAN_ID
        AND LO.CORR_ID = CO.CORR_ID
        AND LO.CORR_ID NOT LIKE '111%'
        AND LO.L_CURRENT_STATUS_ID NOT IN (99,98,97)
        AND HDR.L_INSTITUTION IS NULL
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM WC.CORRES CO,WC.LOANS LO 
    WHERE
        LO.LOAN_ID = HDR.LOAN_ID
        AND LO.CORR_ID = CO.CORR_ID
        AND LO.CORR_ID NOT LIKE '111%'
        AND LO.L_CURRENT_STATUS_ID NOT IN (99,98,97)
        AND HDR.L_INSTITUTION IS NULL

)
```

Comment: it reduced the number of records but still not matching with the select statement